# Play multiple songs in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I wrote this code for iOS to play a song, however I'm not sure how to write the code to play multiple songs.

This is the line of code for a song:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        player.play()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        do
        {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Ken", ofType: "mp3")
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        }
        catch
        {
            //ERROR
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually can play it with just two instances of the AVAudioPlayer resp. every sound file needs it's own AVAudioPlayer if you want to play them simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I already wrote an answer, so I will post even there is already a correct answer. What palme said is correct. You could use multiple AVAudioPlayer instances to play multiple sounds simultaneously:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let paths = ["a","b"]
    var sounds = [AVAudioPlayer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        for path in paths {

            do
            {
                let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: path, ofType: "mp3")

                let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)

                sounds.append(player)

            }
            catch
            {
                //ERROR
            }

        }

        for sound in sounds {
            sound.play()
        }
    }
}
```